# How to replace NaN values with 0 in index dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

[image]

How do I replace the NaN values to 0 while keeping it in this index form?

Answer (score 0):

You can process the original index as a Series first and then re-assign the index:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'Column1': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'Column2': [5, 6, 7, 8], 
'Column3': [8, 9, 10, 11]}, index=['a', 'b', np.nan, np.nan])
df.index = pd.Series(df.index).replace(np.nan, 0)
print df
```

Output:

```
          Column1  Column2  Column3
a           1         5        8
b           2         6        9
0           3         7        10
0           4         8        11
```

Comment: This does not fill na in the index. Please update your code.

Comment: @JoePatten I have updated the code.